# Find newest line in table by date

Tags: r, date

I have a table with three columns,

```
ID      Drug      Date 
ABCDE   A01AA01   2000-01-01
ABCDE   A01AA01   2000-04-01
FGHIJ   A01AA01   2000-02-02
FGHIJ   A01AA01   2000-05-02
...
```

where the date refers to the day the drug was purchased, meaning that for each ID + Drug combination there are multiple dates (since people have to buy their medicine multiple times over the course of a few years). I'm trying to create a new table with the newest instance of every ID + Drug combination, i.e. the last time they purchased the drug. This is probably easy, but I've been struggling with this for a few days and can't find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `df` being your data, this could help:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID,Drug) %>% filter(Date==max(Date))
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your dates are in `Date` objects. (make sure the days/months are correct)

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date), format="%Y-%d-%m")
```

then use

```
aggregate(Date ~ ., df, max)

     ID    Drug       Date
1 ABCDE A01AA01 2000-04-01
2 FGHIJ A01AA01 2000-05-02
```